# K-means on 3D matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am currently learning k-means and wanted to try it on 3D matrix, [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) is the link through which I am passing 2D matrix.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
            [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

But when trying for but when trying with

```
x = [[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]]
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(x)
```

error as

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Any suggestion where I am going wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the docs, [`KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)' `fit` method is expecting:

> X : array-like or sparse matrix, **shape=(n_samples, n_features)**

i.e a 2D shaped array, where each row is a sample, and the columns are the features of each sample. Hence it cannot handle 3D data points.